# How to describe the rate of divergence in this case?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $g_{n}$ be the root of equation 
$$
   \frac{g_{n}}{\ln g_{n}}=\ln n.
$$ How can the asymptotic behavior of $g_{n}$ be described, either by an explicit form of $n$ or by a nice (rate revealing) lower-upper bounds, e.g., $a_{n}\leq g_{n}\leq b_{n}$?

Answer (score 0):

*This is too long for a comment.*

The solution of equation $$\frac x{\log(x)}=a$$ is given explicitly in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$x=-a \,W\left(\frac{-1}{a}\right)$$ Applied to your specific problem, then $$g_n=-\log (n)\, W\left(\frac{-1}{\log (n)}\right)$$ Then, when $n$ becomes larger and larger, we can use the expansion given in the Wikipedia page; around $x=0$ $$W(x)=x-x^2+\frac{3 x^3}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which means that $$g_n=1+\frac{1}{\log(n)}+\frac{3}{2\log^2(n)}+\cdots$$

Using $n=10^k$, the "exact" and approximated values are given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{"exact"} & \text{approximation} \\
 2 & 1.33681 & 1.28788 \\
 3 & 1.18758 & 1.17620 \\
 4 & 1.13061 & 1.12626 \\
 5 & 1.10029 & 1.09818 \\
 6 & 1.08142 & 1.08024 \\
 7 & 1.06854 & 1.06782 \\
 8 & 1.05919 & 1.05871
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Leibovici, wow, so $g_{n}\nrightarrow \infty$?!

Comment: @StudentofStatistics. Well, it seems !

Comment: @Leibovici, I like the word ``seems'' here. We are not sure, are we?

Comment: @StudentofStatistics. Why don't you try to plot ?. Given $g$ compute $n$.